# If $P$ is a projection operator, is $1-P$ also a projection operator?

Tags: operator-algebras

Show that if $P$ is a (hermitian) projection operator, so are (a) $1-P$ and (b) $$ U^{+}PU $$ for any operator $U$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of projection operator is $P\circ P = P$, for (a) you can simply expand $(1-P)\circ (1-P)$ and find it holds true.  You have to define the notation $U^+$ to get an  answer for (b).

Comment: As per my understanding (1-P) (1-P) should be equal to 1-P for 1-P to be Projection.
(1-P) (1-P) = $$1^2-IP-PI+P^2$$
= 1+P
Correct me If i am wrong

Comment: @priyanka: Why would two minuses and a plus make one plus?

Comment: $(1-P)^2=1-2P+P^2=1-2P+P=1-P$

Comment: okay I may be wrong but I interpreted in this way:
1-IP+IP+P = 1+P

Comment: @priyanka: $I$ would hardly be an identity matrix if $P I = -I P = - P$ was valid.

Comment: I wonder I asked such a dumb question... I figured it out.... thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(1-P)^2(x) &=(1-P) \circ ((1-P)(x)) \\
\implies (1-P)^2(x) &=(1-P) \circ (x-P(x)) \\
\implies (1-P)^2(x) &=(x-P(x))-(P(x)-P^2(x)) \\
\end{align}$$
Now using the fact that P is a projection operator, i.e. $P^2=P$, we get:
$$ \begin{align} 
\implies (1-P)^2(x)&=(1-P)(x)-(P(x)-P(x)) \\
\implies (1-P)^2(x)&=(1-P)(x)\\
\end{align} $$

Hence we get $(1-P)^2=(1-P)$, which implies $(1-P)$ is a projection operator.